# Adding onClick events to zabuto calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I've implemented zabuto calendar in my project. Here is the screen shot:
[image: calendar].
I want the color of date cell to be changed when clicked. Here is a part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
                    cell_border: true,
                    today: false,
                    show_days: true,
                    weekstartson: 0,
                    nav_icon: {
                        prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
                        next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here is onClick code.

```
myDateFunction(this.id);
function myDateFunction(id) {
  var date = $("#" + id).data("date");
  document.getElementById("#" + id).style.color = "blue";
}
 $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
            action: function () {
                return myDateFunction(this.id, false);
            },
legend: [
                {type: "text", label: "Special event", badge: "00"},
                {type: "block", label: "Regular event"}
            ]
        });
```

But this isn't working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Wat....where is the code within `myDateFunction` that fires to change the color? How can we know what the elements we need to target are without seeing an HTML markup? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Apologies.... This would be line of code to change the color: `document.getElementById("#" + id).style.color = "blue";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old post, but I've made a custom Zabuto calendar.

It's untested and lot's of features are missing but you should give it a peek:

```
  $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
    language: "fr",
    year: 2015,
    month: 1,
    show_previous: 1,
    show_next: 2,
    // show_reminder: true,
    // show_today: false,
    // show_days: true,
    // weekstartson: 0,
    // nav_icon: {
    //   prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
    //   next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
    // },
    callbacks: {
      on_cell_double_clicked: function() {
        return cellDoubleClicked(this);
      },
      on_cell_clicked: function() {
        return cellClicked(this);
      },
      on_nav_clicked: function() {
        return navClicked(this);
      },
      on_event_clicked: function() {
        return eventClicked(this);
      }
    },
    events: {
      local: events_array,
      ajax: {
        url: "" // load ajax json events here...
      }
    },
    legend: [
      {label: "Rendez-vous", type: "appointment"},
      {label: "Evenement A", type: "eventtype2"},
      {label: "Evenement B", type: "eventtype3"},
      {label: "<span class='fa fa-bell-o'></span> Rappel", type: "reminder"}
    ]
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2gkm4d9/

(try double-click in day wrappers, simple-click on events)

Now with:

- init calendar with local json + ajax data
- call public methods (to add just one event at a time for example)
- add event through a modal (not the modal included in zabuto calendar, I've removed it)
- show a list of events of a day
- ...

It's only few hours of work, there's lot of features to add and things to do to make it stable but it's usable. ;-)

Look carefully to the code... there's much more than the fiddle show actually:

I think you should add a public method really easily to change the color of the cell.

Cheers

Fro

Answer (score 0):

go through this http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/action.html. it contains your answer.